# Java object declaration by assigning to a sub object

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to Java and I have trouble understanding one thing:

When I am declaring an Object by assigning to a sub object (a class extending object), it doesn't have access to sub object attributes.
Why is that ?

Let's say I have this:

```
public class A {
    public int a;
}

public class B extends A {
    public int b;
}
```

When I create an B object like this:

```
A object = new B();
```

I don't have access to `object.b`

I am forced to declare that way

```
B object = new B();
```

Isn't my object supposed to be a B with the first way to ?

Comment: Your *object* is a B -- but the *reference* through which you're calling the method can point to any A object, and is limited to the A interface.

Answer (score 1):

The object is of type `B` only at runtime, at compile time , the compiler does not that its actual type is B since the variable `object` is declared of type `A`, an explicit downcast is required

```
A object = new B();
B b = (B)object;
int x = b.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you called `myfunc()`:

```
A object = myfunc();
```

And I define `myfunc()` as:

```
A myfunc() {
   if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
       return new A();
   } else {
       return new B();
   }
}
```

Can you still expect to always access `object.b`?  No.  `myfunc()` is only promising that it will return something of class A (or derived from class A)